# jq summarize similar elements

Tags: json, jq

I want to use jq to summarize elements with the same description field value.
So that each unique field value of description gets it's own element with the amount field summarized.

I'm using jq 1.5

Before:

```
{ "frames":
  [
    { "description": "Stuff", "amount": 8 },
    { "description": "Stuff", "amount": 4 },
    { "description": "other_stuff", "amount": 2 },
    { "description": "more_stuff", "amount": 20 }
  ]
}
```

After:

```
{ "frames":
  [
    { "description": "Stuff": 12 },
    { "description": "other_stuff", "amount": 2 },
    { "description": "more_stuff", "amount": 20 }
  ]
}
```

Comment: The "After" output is not valid JSON.  Although it would be possible to generate such output using jq, doing so would be highly dubious.  Please clarify.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With your input, the following program produces valid JSON in the spirit of the question:

```
def sum_by(f;g): reduce .[] as $x ({}; .[$x|f] += ($x|g));
.frames |= sum_by(.description; .amount)
```

Using `sum_by` is more efficient than using `group_by` for various reasons.

### Output

```
{
  "frames": {
    "Stuff": 12,
    "other_stuff": 2,
    "more_stuff": 20
  }
}
```

### Variant

If you want `description` and `amount` in the output, you could tweak the above as follows:

```
.frames |= 
  (sum_by(.description; .amount) 
   | to_entries 
   | map( {description: .key, amount: .value} ))
```

The output would then be:

```
{
  "frames": [
    {
      "description": "Stuff",
      "amount": 12
    },
    {
      "description": "other_stuff",
      "amount": 2
    },
    {
      "description": "more_stuff",
      "amount": 20
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Thank you, that was exactly what I was looking for!